# Rails: How can I loop through validation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation

I'm building an API for my app and would like to return errors in the XML response that are generated by validation errors.

So say you're registering on the site, right now the validation errors returned might be:

```
Login has already been taken
Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
Email has already been taken
```

But I'd like to reformat that as:

```
<errors>
    <error>Login has already been taken</error>
    <error>Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)</error>
    <error>Email has already been taken</error>
</errors>
```

So, how would I access the validation error array to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails gives you this functionality by default, i.e.

```
  user.errors.to_xml
```

Will give you

```
=>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <errors>  
     <error>Name can't be blank</error>
     <error>Wiki url can't be blank</error>
     <error>User can't be blank</error>
    </errors>
```

Rails 7

```
user.errors.to_hash.to_xml
```

Comment: Oh nice. Totally forgot about to_xml.

So, how would I put that in my xml.builder file? I tried just dropping it in to a blank builder file but nothing outputs when I do that.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean you want to dump this to a file? OR you want to add extra tags to the generated XML?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in the latest version of Rails.

Comment: @kcdragon which version are you using?

Comment: @HarishShetty I'm using Rails 7

Comment: It looks like Rails 7 removed `to_xml`. But  you can get the XML as follows `user.errors.to_hash.to_xml`

Comment: @kcdragon forgot to tag you in the comment above 

Answer (score 1):

The model object will have an [errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html) object that you can iterate, some examples in the [validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html) doc.

Answer (score 1):

Call #to_xml on errors method

```
user = User.new
unless user.valid?
  return user.errors.to_xml
end
```